# How can I display two different images at alternate succession each by clicking the image in the picturebox?

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to click on the picturebox and display the image and text on label1, the second click to display the second image and the text in label1 as indicated. successive clicks should be able to display the images in alternate succession in that respect.

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click

        `PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.bulb_turned_off_e
        `Label1.Text = "Turn on the light," + TextBox1.Text


        `Label1.Text = "Turn off the light," + TextBox1.Text
        `PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.bulb_when_turned_on_e
```

Comment: Put a bit of thought into it. You want to display image 1 IF image 2 is already displayed, otherwise you want to display image 1. Part of the point of VB is that the syntax reads much like an English sentence so if you say what you want to do in a pseudo-code kinda way, it's virtually VB code already.

Comment: By the way, don't assign to the `Image` property directly from `My.Resources`, because that extracts the data and creates a new object every time. Get each resource once and once only, assign the objects to variables and then use those variables each time. That way, you are using the same `image` objects each time. Make sure to dispose the objects when you're done with them, which is probably when the form closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable `isChanged` (`Private isChanged As Boolean` outside of Sub). And consider at the following code:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    if isChanged = False Then
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.bulb_turned_off_e
        Label1.Text = "Turn on the light," + TextBox1.Text
        isChanged = True ' if not changed, then change image
    Else
        Label1.Text = "Turn off the light," + TextBox1.Text
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.bulb_when_turned_on_e
        isChanged = False ' if changed, then set to back
    End If
End Sub
```

It should work for you. Enjoy!

Comment: Read the comments above about `My.Resources`. Dispose the current image (if any) before you set a new one. `PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()` then set...